# Как и на чем написать свою сетку?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, sass, scss

В общем верстают люди сайты на бустрапе удобно вроде в общем спасибо, но вот что делать если сетка  макета не соответствует бутстрапу? Я знаю, что в таких случаях либо кастомизируют бутстрап, либо пишут свою. Прошерстил весь гугл, и нашел только sasy но там сложно и вообще фу. В общем как написать свою?

Comment: Вот проект смарт-грид: https://github.com/dmitry-lavrik/smart-grid Вот автор проекта: https://dmitrylavrik.ru/video/html-css/smartgrid
здесь же описание, как использовать.

Comment: возьмите отдельно скачайте сетку бутстрапа, замените в scss число столбцов на нужное и брейкпоинты по размерам экрана свои выставите. Больше для сетки настраивать вроде нечего принципиального.

Comment: да и что значит не соответствует? приложите что-ли схему или макет сам, что там у вас не влезает в сетку бутстрапа